# What a typeof keyword inside function parameters declarations means?

Tags: typescript

I've seen in a presentation how to use Typescript with SAPUI5, and in the example code, it was like this:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent", "sap/m/Select"],
  function(UIComponent, Select: typeof sap.m.Select) {
    "use strict";
    // ...
});
```

What is the meaning of the `typeof` keyword in this context? Why didn't the author just write like this:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent", "sap/m/Select"],
  function(UIComponent, Select: sap.m.Select) {
    "use strict";
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [type query](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3810-type-queries). In the example you provided that is being used just as a convenient way to refer to `Select`'s constructor which will probably be used later on to create new instances internally.

Long story short, that function wants its constructor and not an instance of it like you wrote in your second example.

You can [**load this snippet on TS playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20fooNumber%20%3D%2042%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fooString%20%3D%20'foo'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(instance%3A%20Foo%2C%20ctor%3A%20typeof%20Foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(instance.fooNumber)%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(instance.fooString)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(ctor.fooNumber)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(ctor.fooString)%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20anotherInstance%20%3D%20new%20ctor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(anotherInstance.fooNumber)%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(anotherInstance.fooString)%0D%0A%7D) to see the difference:

```
class Foo {
    static fooNumber = 42
    fooString = 'foo'
}

function test(instance: Foo, ctor: typeof Foo) {
    console.log(instance.fooNumber) // Error
    console.log(instance.fooString)
    console.log(ctor.fooNumber)
    console.log(ctor.fooString) // Error

    let anotherInstance = new ctor()
    console.log(anotherInstance.fooNumber) // Error
    console.log(anotherInstance.fooString)
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are treating the word "prototype" and "constructor" interchangeably, but they are distinct.  `typeof Foo` refers to the constructor, not the prototype, which is itself a property of the constructor.  I think you should replace the word "prototype"/"`proto`" with "constructor"/"`ctor`".